# Displaying row sum in a secondary colorbar while plotting matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, matrix, legend

I'm plotting a matrix using `matshow`. I have an array

```
sum = np.sum(A, axis=0)
```

I'd like to display the values stored in `sum` as a secondary legend.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
A = np.arange(0,100).reshape(10,10)
plt.matshow(A)   
plt.colorbar()
```

I would like to know how to add a secondary legend to the above code.

e.g. expected output:

[image]

The legend on the right is created automatically. By secondary legend, I mean the color scale displayed at the bottom. For instance, this could correspond to the sum of the values in each column ( y-axis entries).

Comment: please provide the `A` matrix.

Comment: Hi@MichaelSidorov I think you missed it. It's `A = np.arange(0,100).reshape(10,10)` present in the code block.

Comment: Hi! @Natasha what do you mean by a secondary legend? Do you have an example of a plot that shows what you want?

Comment: Hello @tomjn Could you please check my edit?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to reconsider why you need to represent the column sum on colorbar. Since the color on colorbar represents a value in the matrix. The value of column sum is even not included, what's the meaning of showing column sum with a color bar?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))

A = np.arange(0,100).reshape(10,10)

column_sum = A.sum(axis=0)

im2 = ax.matshow(np.expand_dims(column_sum, axis=0))
# Override upper matrix
im = ax.matshow(A)

fig.colorbar(im2, orientation="horizontal") # Note: the color in this color bar represents value in im2, im2 is override by im. To distinguish it from im, you may interested in https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/custom_cmap.html
fig.colorbar(im)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much .`The value of column sum is even not included` Could you please explain this a bit?

Comment: You could take the colorbar as a `map`. Every color in the matrix can find a coresponding value in the right colorbar. However, for the bottom column sum colorbar, you couldn't find a color coresponding to its color in the matrix.

Comment: I guess that is ok, because I am interested in the sum of the row/column entries of a row/column of interest and not the value in the matrix itself in the second legend.